# Does Thread.Sleep affect ThreadState?

Tags: c#, multithreading

If I create and start a thread, how does calling Thread.Sleep(x) within that thread affect the ThreadState (if at all)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ThreadState defines a set of all
>   possible execution states for threads.
>   Once a thread is created, it is in at
>   least one of the states until it
>   terminates. Threads created within the
>   common language runtime are initially
>   in the Unstarted state, while external
>   threads that come into the runtime are
>   already in the Running state. An
>   Unstarted thread is transitioned into
>   the Running state by calling Start.
>   Not all combinations of ThreadState
>   values are valid; for example, a
>   thread cannot be in both the Aborted
>   and Unstarted states.
>
> **Important**:   Thread state is only of interest in a few debugging
>   scenarios. Your code should never use
>   thread state to synchronize the
>   activities of threads.

ThreadState: **WaitSleepJoin**: The thread is blocked as a result of a call to Wait, Sleep, or Join.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: +1, very helpful, thanks. "Your code should never use thread state to synchronize the activities of threads." Could you elaborate just a little on what you mean by that, thanks!!

Comment: @Pwninstein: it means that you should rely on the provided lock mechanisms to implement synchonization, and not by checking a Thread's state.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate.aspx)

> **WaitSleepJoin**  The thread is blocked.
>   This could be the result of calling
>   Thread.Sleep or Thread.Join, of
>   requesting a lock — for example, by
>   calling Monitor.Enter or Monitor.Wait
>   — or of waiting on a thread
>   synchronization object such as
>   ManualResetEvent.

Short answer is: Yes!

Answer (score 3):

I don't want this to come over as a sarcastic answer, as that won't help anyone - so please take this in the spirit that it was intended.

Have you tried creating a simple winform app with buttons to start, stop and sleep a thread and a status area to show the value of thread.ThreadState?

This will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It transitions to `WaitSleepJoin`.

Answer (score 1):

The thread should be put into ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin.

For details, see [ThreadState's Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate.aspx), specifically:

WaitSleepJoin:  "The thread is blocked. This could be the result of calling Thread..::.Sleep or Thread..::.Join, of requesting a lock — for example, by calling Monitor..::.Enter or Monitor..::.Wait — or of waiting on a thread synchronization object such as ManualResetEvent. "